# Apparent weight: fictitious forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, free-body-diagram

I have this exercise that I have solved

> Mark wants to calculate the acceleration of the lift in his building using a scale and the
> using a weight balance and using the laws of apparent forces in non-inertial systems. As the lift rises upwards, if it goes on the scale, it reads
> on the scale, it reads 62.6 kg; if he does the same
> while the lift is descending, it reads 62.0 kg.
> How much is the acceleration $a$ of the lift?
> And how much does Mark weight "under normal conditions"?

**Hint**: The textbook it is in Italian language and I like not very much because in this exercise it is confusing between weight with the mass.

\begin{cases}
(F_{\text{fict}_{\text{up}}})=m_{\text{Mark}} \ g + m_{\text{Mark}}\ a & (1) \\
(F_{\text{fict}_{\text{down}}})=m_{\text{Mark}} \ g - m_{\text{Mark}}\ a 
\end{cases}

Hence

$$(F_{\text{fict}_{\text{up}}})+(F_{\text{fict}_{\text{down}}})=2 m_{\text{Mark}}\ g$$

If $(F_{\text{fict}_{\text{up}}})=(m_{\text{fict}_{\text{up}}}) g$ and $(F_{\text{fict}_{\text{down}}})=(m_{\text{fict}_{\text{down}}}) g$ I found $m_{\text{Mark}}$.

Definitively from the $(1)$ for example I will have

$$a=\frac{m_{\text{fict}_{\text{up}}}g - mg}{m_{\text{Mark}}}$$

> My question is: $(F_{\text{fict}_{\text{up}}})$ or $(F_{\text{fict}_{\text{down}}})$ is it always

$$(m_{\text{fict}_{\text{up}}}) g \quad \text{ or } \quad (m_{\text{fict}_{\text{down}}}) g \quad ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree. From the question you quoted, I don't like that textbook either.

It says the scale is marked in kg, which is a unit of mass, not force. That is OK for normal use when you just want a gadget that measures your mass, and you don't care how it works.

But here, the question is asking you to use it as an instrument to measure force. So you have to figure out when it tells you a mass, what is the force that makes it do so. Because it is designed to work in a frame of reference at rest with respect to the surface of the Earth, the force is $F = mg$.

You now you can translate the question into better terms. When the scale reads $62.6 \space kg$, the force is $mg = 62.6 \space kg * 9.8 \space m/s^2 = 613.5 N$. When the scale reads $62 \space kg$ the force is $607.6 \space N$.

The second confusing thing is how lifts work. Again from a frame of reference at rest with respect to the Earth, A lift starts at rest. It accelerates until it reaches its design speed. The it travels up or down at constant speed.

You must guess that the problem is telling you the scale reading during these periods of acceleration. You must assume the lift accelerates uniformly so you can get a sensible reading. You must assume that the acceleration up and down are equally strong.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer...and I approved it.